# Proofs: Subspaces, vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Studying for an exam, came across this question:

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$ but $u \notin V$.
    $W = \{v + cu: v$ is in $V$ and $c$ is a scalar$\}$

A) Prove that $W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Certainly we have to use the definition of closure under vector addition and the definition of closure under scalar multiplication. But how?

B) Determine the dimension of $W$. Justify your answer.

Comment: What are the steps to determining the dimension of $W$?

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$
W = \{v + cu\mid v\in V, c\in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
and you want first to show that $W$ is a vector space. To do this, [you can look up all the conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) that need to be satisfied and check them.

For example you need to check that if $w_1$ and $w_2$ are in $W$, then $w_1 + w_2$ is also in $W$. So assume that such two are given and that 
$$
w_1 = v_1 + c_1u \\
w_2 = v_2 + c_2u
$$
Then
$$
w_1 + w_2 = (v_1 + v_2) + (c_1 + c_2)u.
$$
This is in $W$ because $v_1 + v_2$ is a vector in $V$ and $c_1 + c_2$ is a scalar.

Again, you can look up other conditions that you need to check. They are all similar to the one I have shown here.

For the second part I suggest that you let $\{e_1, \dots, e_m\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then from that you try to get a basis for $W$.

Comment: This condition is the vector addition, right?

Comment: @SolBethanyReaves: That's right. This condition is that the space is closed under addition of two vectors.

Answer (score 2):

About part $1$ I agree with thomas!
But about part $2$:
you know $u$ is independence with basis of subspace $V$ (because it is not generated by them (we have $u \notin V$) )

now supose $\{v_{1}, \cdots \cdots,v_{m}\}$be a basis for V

then $\{0+cu,v_{1}+cu,\cdots \cdots,v_{m}+cu\}$ will be a basis for $W$ ($V$ is subspace and has $0$) and

so $\dim (W)=\dim(V)+1$

Answer (score 0):

a) yes, you have to show that $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is closed under the vector addition and scalar multiplication inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$ (take general elements of $W$)

b) take a basis of $V$ and extend it to a basis of $W$

Comment: I see. But I'm not sure how to go about (b). I understand (a) now.

Comment: if $V$ has dimension $j$ then there are vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_j$ that form a basis of $V$. now what do you think would be a good candidate vector to add to this collection in order to form a basis for $W$? you'll have to show that this new collection is linearly independent and spans $W$. the dimension of $W$ will be the size of the basis i.e. $j+1$

Comment: Since u does not belong to V, (and therefore linearly independent) we can use vector u to form the basis for W. But I'm not sure how correctly write the answer if this was asked on an exam other what I just wrote and conclude that the dimension W = 1 + dimension of V.

Comment: then write it your way; do you have a feeling the conclusion follows logically? if not, what can you do to revise it? math proofs are about logic, and if you don't have that in you, no one can teach it to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

For part $a$, in addition to showing $W$ is close under addition and scalar multiplication, you also need to show that the zero vector is in $W$ as well.
That is true because $V$ is a subspace so $v$ can be $0$. Since $c$ is a scalar, $c$ can be $0$ as well. So $w=v+cu$ can be $0$. Done.`

Comment: actually, once you prove that either addition or scalar multiplication is closed in $W$, this follows from the fact that $W$ is nonempty (since $V$ is nonempty)